# AWS QLDB - Java Tutorial Step 2 (ConnectToLeger) - Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized

Tags: java, amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-qldb

I am trying to run the Java Tutorial from AWS found here:
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/getting-started.java.tutorial.html

In the first step of the guide I had to add the region and endpoint to the "getClient" method, to get it to run. On step two I get an error on connecting to the ledger.

```
Exception in thread "main" com.amazonaws.services.qldbsession.model.AmazonQLDBSessionException: Unable to determine service/operation name to be authorized (Service: AmazonQLDBSession; Status Code: 403; Error Code: AccessDeniedException; Request ID
```

I know my IAM user has the correct permissions, because I could add the ledger with it, and for now it has full access to QLDB. I have tried setting the region and endpoint specific in the "createQldbDriver" method, and the "credentials" to be sure it was using the IAM user I want, even though I know my credentials are correct in aws/credentials file.
No matter what I try, I keep getting the exception shown above.

I hope someone can point me in the right direction.

Comment: please check whether your AWS access key ID has a subscription for this service or not. also check this [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/CommonErrors.html).

Comment: Hi, thank you for the input. I have already signed up for the QLDB in the AWS console, the IAM user has full access to QLDB, and as mentioned I also created a ledger with that IAM user, which I can see in the console. I started with the common errors, but none of them seem to relate to my issue.

Answer (score 2):

I'm wondering if you have a dependency issue in your application such as an incompatible version of the QLDB Driver and AWS SDK. Can you confirm the versions match (at least) the guidance in https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/getting-started.java.html#getting-started.java.prereqs

```
dependencies {
    compile group: 'software.amazon.qldb', name: 'amazon-qldb-driver-java', version: '1.0.2'
    compile group: 'com.amazonaws', name: 'aws-java-sdk-qldb', version: '1.11.628'
    compile group: 'com.fasterxml.jackson.dataformat', name: 'jackson-dataformat-ion', version: '2.10.0.pr1'
}
```

If that doesn't do the trick, please will you update your question with more information such as the changes you made to the tutorial code (be sure to not include any credentials if you've chosen to inline them!) and the full-stack trace. It's OK to share a request id publicly.

**UPDATE:** Another shot in the dark: is it possible you customized the endpoint when building the client driver? If so, did you perhaps mix the control and session endpoints up?

Comment: that was the case for me, I used control endpoint instead of session endpoint.  
You can retrieve endpoints list here https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/qldb.html   (sessions endpoints are on the second array)

Answer (score 0):

There are different service endpoints for QLDB please see the sample endpoints below. Please check that you used the right end point to connect. Please check below QLDB [documentation](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/general/latest/gr/qldb.html)

Control plane : qldb.us-east-1.amazonaws.com

Transactional Data Plane: session.qldb.us-east-2.amazonaws.com

Answer (score 0):

Is not neccesary modify endpoint nor region variables in CreateLedger or ConnectToLEdger class.

just modify this:

in CreateLedger.getClient method:

return builder
.withRegion(Regions.US_EAST_1)
.build();

in ConnectToLedger.getAmazonQldbSessionClientBuilder method:

return builder.region(Region.US_EAST_1);

with these changes, you let SDK find the right endpoint for control plane an transactional data plane.

please review https://docs.aws.amazon.com/qldb/latest/developerguide/getting-started.java.html#getting-started.java.prereqs